# Starting and stopping services in vespa

Tags: vespa

In the benchmarking page "https://docs.vespa.ai/en/performance/vespa-benchmarking.html" it is given that we need to restart the services after we increase the persearch thread using the commands vespa-stop-services and vespa-start-services.
Could you tell us if we need to do this on all the content nodes or just the config nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deploying a change that requires a restart,  the deploy command will list the actions you need to take. For example when changing the global per search thread setting changing from 2 to 5 in the below example:

```
curl --header Content-Type:application/zip --data-binary @target/application.zip   localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/prepareandactivate |jq . 
{
    "log": [
        {
            "time": 1645036778830,
            "level": "WARNING",
            "message": "Change(s) between active and new application that require restart:\nIn cluster 'mycluster' of type 'search':\n    Restart services of type 'searchnode' because:\n        1) # Number of threads used per search\nproton.numthreadspersearch has changed from 2 to 5\n"
        }
    ],
    "tenant": "default",
    "url": "http://localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/application/default/environment/prod/region/default/instance/default",
    "message": "Session 8 for tenant 'default' prepared and activated.",
    "configChangeActions": {
        "restart": [
            {
                "clusterName": "mycluster",
                "clusterType": "search",
                "serviceType": "searchnode",
                "messages": [
                    "# Number of threads used per search\nproton.numthreadspersearch has changed from 2 to 5"
                ],
                "services": [
                    {
                        "serviceName": "searchnode",
                        "serviceType": "searchnode",
                        "configId": "mycluster/search/cluster.mycluster/0",
                        "hostName": "vespa-container"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "refeed": [],
        "reindex": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift response!

Comment: @KRoy, if the answer solved your problem, please use the check mark to accept it, instead of adding a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers